# Can't open image after decoding and writing to disk

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, image-uploading

I am uploading a jpg to a spring controller endpoint. The image is uploaded as Base64 image/jpg which comes in as a MultipartFile. I am decoding the inputstream using Base64Decoder which seems to decode it ok but when I turn it into an InputStream to write it out to disk I can see it's been modified (according to what I can see in the debugger). When I save the file and open it it says it's an unsupported file type.

I took the multipart inputstream and wrote it directly to disk and I see the base64 encoding in notepad.

> data:image/jpeg;base64,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

Here's my controller and my code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveBlueprintOrder")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveBlueprintOrder(@RequestParam MultipartFile blueprint,
                                            @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile coversheet,
                                            @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile logo,
                                            @ModelAttribute BlueprintOrder blueprintOrder) { 


if(coversheet != null) {

           BASE64Decoder decoder1 = new BASE64Decoder();
           byte[] imageBytes = decoder1.decodeBuffer(coversheet.getInputStream());
           InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
           BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
           ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\i58287\\Downloads\\coversheet.jpg"));


            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\i58287\\Downloads\\coversheet-test.jpg");
            stream.write(imageBytes);
            stream.close();
```

I just need to be able to translate this image to an inputstream so I can check the image locally in addition I need to send it to another api as such. What am I missing that's causing this image to be un-openable? Thanks for any help!

PS: I've done a lot of combinations so this is showing a couple options I have tried, BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis) keeps returning a null image.

Comment: And you're sure that the data actually represents a JPG image and not a different image type with a .jpg file extension?

Comment: Yes because I am testing it from my front end therefore I can control what file it being uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know WHY this is what I had to do but I ended up saving my byte[] as a String and cut off the pre-pended

> data:image/jpeg;base64

Then I decoded it into an InputStream. Anyone know why I had to do this?

Here's the code:

```
 String imageBytes = new String(coversheet.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String imageDataBytes = imageBytes.substring(imageBytes.indexOf(",") + 1);
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes()));
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\i58287\\Downloads\\coversheet-test.jpg"));
```